# Instantiate 5 timers for 5 tables dynamically (UNITY 3D)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a question. I do have 5 table objects and it needs 5 timers so 1 timer per each table

I created a script which is called `Table.cs`

**Table.cs**

```
public UILabel info_timer = null;
```

And I have my main script lets call it `Main.cs`

**Main.cs**

```
const float gap = 20.0f;
Table[] script_table;
bool start_timer = false;
int t_no;
public static string Ctimer = "";

void Update()
{

     int i = returnTableNo(t_no);

     if (i != -1 && script_tables != null && script_tables[i] != null)
     {
           gap -= Time.deltaTime();

           if(gap <= 0.0f)
           {
                script_table[i].info_timer =  Ctimer = "[808080]0[-]";
           }
           else
           {
                script_table[i].info_timer.text = gap.ToString("F0");
           }
      }
 }

 //someone will call this to make start_timer to true;
 void ActivateTimer(){
     t.tableno = t_no;
     start_timer = true;
 }

//this line of code is for the table no == table no
int returnTableNo(int table_no)
{
   //table is equavalent to 5 for now
    for (int i = 0; i < table.Count; i++)
    {
        if (t.table_no == table_no)
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Now I'm quite confused on how to put each timer on every table I have. Because the scenario I'm having is that for example

The table 1 is operating right only table 1 timer will the only one who will start the timer but what's happening is that all the table timer are running even though some of my tables is not operating.

They are operating when his command is being called

```
GCommand.start_:
```

Here's a drawing so that you can visualize what I am trying to do.

[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mefx5.png)

Thank you to someone who will help me.

Comment: Whenever I say to myself "I need an X for every Y" I create a field in X for a Y and I'm done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could hold the timer functionality in one of two (in general) places. The first would be in your Main.cs, and the second would be in your Table.cs. There'd be pro's and con's to each method. My preference would be to modify Table.cs to basically allow for either style to be used, but the following example leans for towards doing all of the processing within each Table.

Using Table.cs to encapsulate the functionality example:

```
// If Table.cs is derived from MonoBehaviour, the Update() method can be
// used to drive the timer. But adds the inherit overhead of being a MonoBehaviour.
public class Table : MonoBehaviour
{
  public UILabel info_timer = null;

  const float gap = 20.0f;

  private float timer;
  public bool isActive { get; private set; } = false;

  public void ActivateTimer( bool activate = true)
  {
    // If activate is true, then reset this timer to the default.
    if ( activate )
      timer = gap;
    isActive = activate;
  }

  // Use Update to drive the timer from each components Update call? Ignored if this class does not derive from MonoBehaviour.
  public void Update()
  {
    UpdateTimer(Time.deltaTime);
  }

  // Use an explicit update method to drive the timer.
  public void UpdateTimer( float deltaTime)
  {
    // We can even check to see if the table is active or the timer has already timed out.
    if ( !isActive ) return;

    timer -= deltaTime;

    if ( timer <= 0.0f )
    {
      script_table[i].info_timer =  Ctimer = "[808080]0[-]";
      isActive = false;
    }
    else
      script_table[i].info_timer.text = gap.ToString("F0");
  }
}
```

Using Main.cs to drive all of the updates for all tables, instead of the Table Update methods:

```
public class Main : MonoBehaviour
{
  const float gap = 20.0f;
  Table[] script_table;
  bool start_timer = false;
  int t_no;
  public static string Ctimer = "";

  public void Update()
  {
    for ( int i = 0; i < script_table.Length; i++ )
      script_table[i].UpdateTimer(Time.deltaTime);
  }

  // This method can now be used to Activate or De-Activate a timer.
  public void ActivateTimer ( int tableNumber, bool activate = true )
  {
    script_table[tableNumber ].ActivateTimer( activate );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi sir . I'm still using c# 4.0 and it gives me an error saying `error CS1644: Feature `auto-implemented property initializer' cannot be used because it is not part of the C# 4.0 language specification`

Comment: and could you explain more sir when I can use this `ActivateTimer ()`

Comment: You can remove the "`= false`" from `isActive { get; private set; } = false;' because the property will default to 'false'. I just wanted to be thorough.

Comment: It looked like you wanted to be able to start timers for your `Table` class instances. So, when the user is ready to enable the timer, simply call something like : `ActivateTime(1);` I noticed I should have also made `Main.cs` derive from `MonoBehaviour`.

Comment: `ActivateTimer(int, bool)` has a activate default of `true` so the timer is activated. But there's a little bit of code there that would allow you to reset the timer if you needed to. I don't know what the needs of your program are, but it was an extra line or two for the feature.

Answer (score 1):

I for one created a Clock class and a ClockManager class (singleton). That way I can create instances of timers which are then automatically added to a list in the ClockManager. It uses the MonoBehavior Update (Only one is used for everything! That's also better for performance.) to invoke a "tick" for all Timers, each of whom can have their own triggering intervals. Be it 0.0 sec (meaning with each update), every 0.1 sec, every 2.0 sec, etc. When they are triggered, they invoke a given System.Action to which they pass the interval value or a multiple of it (if multiple intervals have been reached within one update tick).

Usage is simple:

```
Clock idleClock = new Clock (this, DoIdleCheck, 0.5f);
// Parameters: 1. Reference to the object for automatic destruction.
// 2. The target method to invoke. 3. Interval.
```

There is too much code to copy paste it here as it is a lot interwoven with my other code. But this way you can use any amount of timers for anything you want, and pause or start them as needed. Of course you can implement it in simple ways as well.